# Is there a drawback creating android applications using old sdk version?

Tags: android, sdk

Is there a drawback creating android applications using old sdk version? Other than the obvious one; you can't use the newer functions. Will this application slower if I set build target an old sdk compared to the latest api version when executed on a device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, not being able to use the new features is obvious. But it depends on what you are targeting and your user base is. In general, it depends on what you are trying to do. A game will usually want to use OPEN GL ES 2.0 so you need the android version that supports that. If you don't care about a specific feature it is best to follow this:

http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

for an idea on a potential market share of an application. Older phones will increase the potential market. Besides versions you also need to know if you want to target an tablet or phone. That includes different UI changes/looks.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use new features, of course, if you don't need any new features there is no problem. You will also be able to deploy an application that users with older phones will be able to usecas well.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is no drawback other than not being able to use new features.
No, your application will not be slower.